# If $c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^2tf(t)dt$, where $f$ is a positive continuous function, then find the value of $c$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, continuity

If $c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^2tf(t)dt$, where $f$ is a positive continuous function, then find the value of $c.$

My attempt:

> Given, $c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^2tf(t)dt.$ We can write this given equality as $c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^2xf(x)dx.$ Now, $$c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^2xf(x)dx\implies c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^1xf(x)dx+\int_1^1xf(x)dx\implies c\int_0^1xf(2x)dx=\int_0^1xf(x)dx.$$

From this, can we directly write, that $cxf(2x)=xf(x)$? (Since, its given $f$ is a positive continuous function) However, I can't proceed after this. I think there might be numerous posts concerning the same topic, but I couldn't find them either...

Comment: Hint: try a u-substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your attempt works because $\int_0^2\neq\int_0^1+\int_1^1.$

Anyway, $c$ is found by integral by substitution $t=2x$ ;

$\int_0^2 tf(t)dt=4\int_0^1 xf(2x)dx$.

Thus $c=4$ works.

**Edit for comments**

You did $$\int_0^2 xf(x)dx=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx+\int_1^1 xf(x)dx$$ but this doesn't hold(counter example : $f(x)\equiv 1$).

If you separate the interval of integral, it should be $$\int_0^2 xf(x)dx=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx+\int_1^{\color{red}{2}} xf(x)dx$$

Comment: @da Thank you!  Can you please elaborate the reason, why my attemt do not work ?

Comment: @da To be specific, why $\int_0^2\neq\int_0^1+\int_1^1$ ?

Comment: I added the explanation for that. @Franklin

Comment: @da Thanks!.....